# SQL joins with not exits

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, inner-join

```
SocialStatus
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ SocialStatusId | SocialTypeId | ResidentId | Details | IsActive ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║       16       |      5       |      2     | Sample  |     1    ║
║       17       |      6       |      4     | kgfhkhgf|     0    ║
║       18       |      8       |      2     | NULL    |     1    ║
║       19       |      8       |      6     | NULL    |     0    ║
║       21       |      5       |      8     | asdasd  |     1    ║
║       22       |      5       |      3     | adasd   |     0    ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Resident
╔════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ResidentId ║ FirstName ║ MiddleName ║ LastName ║ Birthdate  ║ Address ║ GenderId ║ ContactNumber ║ IsNonResident ║ IsActive ║ StreetId ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║          8 ║ Jonathan  ║ Santos     ║ Guinto   ║ 2016-11-17 ║ Sample  ║        1 ║   09107435739 ║             0 ║        1 ║ NULL     ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════╩══════════╝

SocialType
╔══════════════╦════════════════════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ SocialTypeId ║       SocialName       ║ Description ║ IsActive ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║            1 ║ Sample                 ║ Sample0001  ║        0 ║
║            2 ║ Sample2                ║ Sample222   ║        0 ║
║            3 ║ Sample3                ║ Sample3123  ║        0 ║
║            4 ║ Sample4                ║ Sample4     ║        0 ║
║            5 ║ Person with disability ║ Happy       ║        1 ║
║            6 ║ Señior Citizen         ║ Sample      ║        1 ║
║            7 ║ Unemployed             ║ sample      ║        1 ║
║            8 ║ Indigence              ║ sample      ║        1 ║
║            9 ║ Rowllens               ║ asdasdasd   ║        0 ║
║           10 ║                        ║             ║        0 ║
╚══════════════╩════════════════════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

From top to buttom is

- SocialStatus
- Resident
- SocialType

what i want to do is to join SocialType and SocialStatus table then filter if Resident has this i.e. **Señior Citizen** then a bit column assign to **true** to illustrate more please see output table

My query

```
SELECT 
    st.SocialTypeId,
    st.SocialName,
    CASE WHEN ss.SocialStatusId IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END AS IsAssign
FROM dbo.SocialType st
LEFT JOIN dbo.SocialStatus ss ON st.SocialTypeId = ss.SocialTypeId
WHERE ss.IsActive = 1 AND ss.ResidentId = 8
```

this query return only a single column of **SocialType** table
output is

```
╔══════════════╦════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ SocialTypeId ║       SocialName       ║ IsAssign ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║            5 ║ Person with disability ║        1 ║
╚══════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Desire output is something like this

```
╔══════════════╦════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ SocialTypeId ║       SocialName       ║ IsAssign ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════╣
║            5 ║ Person with disability ║        1 ║
║            6 ║ Señior Citizen         ║        0 ║
║            7 ║ Unemployed             ║        0 ║
║            8 ║ Indigence              ║        0 ║
╚══════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: HOW the query returns single column only ?!!

Comment: Please give name to all the tables, it's very confusing and post your desired output instead of what your query is returning.

Comment: @Suraz i already updated the question, and the desired output is already posted, see the last table output thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Desire result, Try the next:

```
select 
        distinct st.SocialTypeId, 
        SocialName, 
        CASE 
            WHEN ss.SocialStatusId IS NULL 
            THEN CAST(1 AS bit) 
            ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) 
            END AS IsAssign
from 
        SocialType st left outer join SocialStatus ss
on      
        st.SocialTypeId = ss.SocialTypeId
where 
        st.IsActive = 1
```

The **Results** will be as next:-

[image]

**Note:**

About `column` "IsAssign", your desire result was `1` for `SocialTypeId` equlas `5` altought `ss.SocialStatusId` has number ! , so the result will be `0` according to `CASE` cluse that you used, is there is somting wrong, kindly revisit your CASE cluse.

---

**UPDATE depends on below comment-**

For Filtering `ss.residentId =8` Use it in join Conditions rather than Where clause.

as following:-

```
select 
        distinct st.SocialTypeId, 
        SocialName, 

        CASE 
            WHEN ss.SocialStatusId IS NOT NULL
            THEN CAST(1 AS bit) 
            ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) 
            END AS IsAssign
from 
        SocialType st left outer join SocialStatus ss
on      
        st.SocialTypeId = ss.SocialTypeId and
        ss.residentId =8
where 
        st.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @ahmed abdelqader its really really close, but when i try to filter residentId  = 8, the person with disability return twice please see the link https://s28.postimg.org/909gjgawt/query.png 
https://s28.postimg.org/wfrdosunx/result.png

Comment: @armory09 the answer has updated, plz visit it, waiting ur feedback.

Comment: Glad to help u dude :)